# How is the circle parameterization $(x,y)=(-a\sin t,a(1-\cos t))$ established?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For a question on finding the equation of a companion curve, I've seen a parameterisation of a circle as
$$x=-a\sin t \qquad y=a(1-\cos t)$$ and I am unsure how this has been established? The example I was looking at didn't really explain this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Have you tried plotting the circle and then considering how you might adjust the standard parameterization $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ to fit?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y=a-a\cos t$ so your two equations give a circle in the $x,y$ plane with center at $(0,a)$ and radius $a.$

Check: $(x-0)^2+(y-a)^2=[-a \sin t]^2+[-a \cos t]^2=a^2[\sin^2 t +\cos^2 t]=a^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Let's first verify that this is a circle. The general equation of a circle is $$(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$$
In your equation for $x$ and $y$, we need to get rid of parameter $t$. You notice that the equations contain $\sin t$ and $\cos t$, so let's use $$\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t=1$$
Then $$\sin t=-\frac xa\\\cos t=-\frac{y-a}a$$
This yields $$x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$$
So you parametrize the circle of radius $a$, with the center at $(0,a)$. Now looking at the equations for $x$ and $y$, we can see that $t$ is an angle along the circle, with the vertex in the center of the circle. We need to figure out where is the angle measured from, and in which direction is positive. For that, we set $t=0$, so $x=0$ and $y=0$, so we measure from the bottom of the circle. If you just increase $t$ a little, $x$ will become negative, and $y$ is positive, so we move along the circle in a clockwise direction.